# Making a virgin version of this cocktail

Tags: recommendations, cocktails, ingredients, mocktails, mixology

So, I have a cocktail that I think tastes very good and I want to do an alcohol free version of it. The problem is that I have no idea what would be a good substitution for the alcohol in the cocktail. My question is simply if anyone has any suggestion for what to substitute the alcohol with. I hope this question is acceptable here. I'll give the recipe below along with pictures of the alcohol used.

Recipe:

---

**Cinnabun cocktail**:

| Ingredient | Amount (mL) |
| --- | --- |
| Fireball | 10 |
| Joseph Carton Pomme Verte | 10 |
| Disaronno (Amaretto) | 20 |
| Lemon juice | 20 |
| Simple syrup (1:1) | 30 |
| Eggwhite | 10 |

I reverse-dry shake this (wet shake without eggwhite, then dryshake) and then dump it in a rocks glas (I dump it so that I get the rough texture and small ice crystals). Also There is cinnabun as garnish (I just use powder).

Here is a picture of the alcohol used (sorry for poor quality):

[image]

From left to right: Pomme Verte, Disaronno, Fireball

---

So what I am looking for is something to replace the alcohol. Preferably something that is not too rare or hard to obtain. Can anyone help me with suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Oddly enough, I have never heard of Pomme Verte... but this sounds amazing, I'm going to have to try this.
My thinking here - sorry if I over complicate.  For the Pomme Verte - i don't know how strong it's flavor is,but I would start with apple juice and dilute it with water and maybe add a bit of sour mix to off set the sweet. Or dilute with water and add simple syrup - and adjust accordingly. For amaretto, unless its disaranno, you won't find anything close to it even with alcohol... I might low slow boil one off in the event of your mocktail not working out right.  But, Finest Call makes an amaretto flavored mixer, I would try that first, for price and availability. Then, for fireball, the toughest substitute, there is a website enjoymocktails.com and they sell a cinnamon fire bottle for $34. If the other 2 work, i would try this. You can also get ammaretto NA here, but cost wise, I would start with Finest Call.
Hope this helps. I am having to assume a lot, as living in Alaska, nothing is easy to obtain or cost effective.  Although i just noticed you had not mentioned the cost part...I  somehow added that in to your question.  In that case, I might use the liquors themselves, boil them down to a concentrate and the dilute with water. It won't be 100% alcohol free,but like na beers and cooking with alcohol. It will be greatly reduced.